# droidscanner app displaying error with WifiManager getsystemservice class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, wifimanager

I'm working on a network scanner app, and it is giving me errors with WifiManager class and method getSystemService method on AsyncTask in IpScanActivity. I have used the same class on main activity no problem there, but when I use it again on IpScanActivity is complaining. I would like to pass the WifiInfo from main activity to IpScanActivity, but haven't found how. I guess by instantiating IpScanactivity (don't know if that's the way to do it) anyway. why I'm getting the getSystemService on IpScanActivity. Thanks in advance.
Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnReadNet;
    TextView textResult;
    ListView listViewNode;
    ArrayList<String> networkList;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterNet;
    public String ip;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnReadNet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read_network);
        textResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        listViewNode = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.nodelist);
        networkList = new ArrayList<>();

        adapterNet = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, networkList);
        listViewNode.setAdapter(adapterNet);

        WifiManager wifiMan = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMan.getConnectionInfo();
        int ipAddress = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
        ip  = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
        textResult.setText(printOutput(wifiInfo));



        //starting network scanner activity on button press
        btnReadNet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent scanNetIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IpScanActivity.class);
                startActivity(scanNetIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    public String printOutput(WifiInfo wifiInfo) {
        return "Local IP: " + ip + "\n" +
                "SSID: " + wifiInfo.getSSID() + "\n" +
                "BSSID: " + wifiInfo.getBSSID() + "\n" +
                "MAC: " + wifiInfo.getMacAddress() + "\n" +
                "Signal: " + wifiInfo.getRssi() + "db" + "\n" +
                "Speed: " + wifiInfo.getLinkSpeed() + "Mbps" + "\n" +
                "Frequency: " + wifiInfo.getFrequency() + "MHz" + "\n" +
                "Connection: " + wifiInfo.getSupplicantState();
    }
}
```

IpScanActivity class

```
public class IpScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String ip;
    String mac;
    ArrayList<Node> hostList;
    ListView networkScan;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.scan_list);

        hostList = new ArrayList<>();

        //inflating adapter
        networkScan  = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scan_list);
        NodeAdapter networkAdapter = new NodeAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, hostList);
        networkScan.setAdapter(networkAdapter);

        //scanning network
        TaskScanNetwork scanNetwork = new TaskScanNetwork();
        scanNetwork.execute();



    }

    /*
       * AscynTask to scan the network
       * you should try different timeout for your network/devices
       * it will try to detect localhost ip addres and subnet. then
       * it will use subnet to scan network
       *
       */
    private class TaskScanNetwork extends AsyncTask<Void, Node, Void> {

        String localIp;
        String mac;
        String subnet;
        static final int lower = 1;
        static final int upper = 254;
        static final int timeout = 1000;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            WifiManager wifiMan1 = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo1 = wifiMan1.getConnectionInfo();
            int ipAddress = wifiInfo1.getIpAddress();
            localIp  = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
            Log.v("Ip Address: ", localIp);
            //subnet = ip.substring(0, ip.lastIndexOf("."));
            hostList.clear();
            //textResult.setText("Scanning Network...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = lower; i <= upper; i++) {
                ip = subnet + "." + i;
                Log.v("Host: ", ip);

                try {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                    if (inetAddress.isReachable(timeout)) {
                        Node newNode = new Node(ip);
                        publishProgress(newNode);
                    }

                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Node... values) {
            hostList.add(values[0]);
            networkScan.deferNotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            //result.setText("Live Hosts: ");
        }
    }

}
```

Node class

```
public class Node {
    String ip;
    String mac;
    String CanonicalHostName;
    String HostName;
    String remark;
    boolean isReachable;

    Node(String ip){
        this.ip = ip;
        //this.mac = mac;
        this.isReachable = true;
    }

    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public String getHostName() {
        return HostName;
    }

    public String getMac() {
        return mac;
    }

    public String getRemark() {
        return remark;
    }

    public boolean isReachable() {
        return isReachable;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "IP: " + ip + "\n" +
                "MAC: " + mac + "\n" +
                "CanonicalHostName:\t" + CanonicalHostName + "\n" +
                "HostName:\t" + HostName + "\n" +
                "isReachable: " + isReachable +
                "\n" + remark;
    }

    private void queryHost(){
        try {
            InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
            CanonicalHostName = inetAddress.getCanonicalHostName();
            HostName = inetAddress.getHostName();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            remark = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            remark = e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

NodeAdapter class

```
public class NodeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Node>{

    public NodeAdapter(Context context, int num, ArrayList<Node> allHost) {
        super(context, 0, allHost);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Get the data item for this position
        Node host = getItem(position);
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }
        // Lookup view for data population
        TextView nodeIpTxtView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.node_ip);
        TextView nodeMacTxtView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.node_mac);
        // Populate the data into the template view using the data object
        nodeIpTxtView.setText(host.getIp());
        nodeMacTxtView.setText(host.getMac());
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```